# Creating a list of dictionary objects from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries from a csv file similar to below

```
name,age,gender  
jack,20,male  
rose,18,female
```

so that the dictionary would read

```
a= [{'name':'jack', 'age':20, 'gender':'male'}, {'name':'rose', 'age':18, 'gender':'female'}]
```

However, I'm not allowed to use dictReader or anything kind of reader (not allowed to use 'with' either). How can I do this using the most basic statements?

Comment: Not being allowed to use `with` is a pretty weird restriction.  Are you allowed to use `open`?  `for`?  `in`?  `split`?  `strip`?  `list`?  `=`?  What exactly falls under the heading of "basic statements"?

Comment: Yes, allowed to use all of those. We haven't learned `with` yet so are not allowed to use it, and I've seen it while searching for a solution online

Answer (score 2):

Read the first line to build a list of the keys, and then iterate through the remaining lines to assign the values.  Use `strip` to remove the linebreaks and any other dangling whitespace, and `split(",")` to split each line.

```
csv = open("titanic.txt")
keys = next(csv).strip().split(",")
print([{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, row.strip().split(","))} for row in csv])
csv.close()
```

```
[{'name': 'jack', 'age': '20', 'gender': 'male'}, {'name': 'rose', 'age': '18', 'gender': 'female'}]
```

Equivalently, with `csv.DictReader`:

```
from csv import DictReader

csv = open("titanic.txt")
print(list(DictReader(csv)))
csv.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this without `zip` as well?

Comment: There is, but if you wanted me to write it for you, you should have included that in the list of banned words.  :)  You can read all about how it works here, and then work out from there how to reimplement it yourself: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/zip-method